# GitHubにpushしたアプリがTravis CIでビルドされない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, travis-ci

**やりたいこと**

Dockerで環境構築したRailsのアプリをGitHubにpushする際、Travis CIでテストを実行、buildしたい。

**状況**

Dockerのコンテナの中で`rails test`を実行しても問題無い。
アプリがlocalhostで起ち上がることは確認済み。

docker-compose.ymlの中身

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  db-data:

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/product-register'
    environment:
      - 'DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres'
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - 'db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust'
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres'
```

.travis.ymlの中身

```
sudo: required

services: docker

before_install:
  - docker login -u polymetisoutis -p 5fb47200-dd19-4772-a9ad-c98913ef1cb9
  - docker-compose up --build -d

script:
  - docker-compose exec --env 'RAILS_ENV=test' web rails db:create
  - docker-compose exec --env 'RAILS_ENV=test' web rails db:migrate
  - docker-compose exec --env 'RAILS_ENV=test' web rails test
```

GitHub⇒https://github.com/PolymetisOutis/product-register

**至った経緯**

`git add .`
`git commit -m ""`
した後、
`git push origin master`
をしました。
`git push origin master`
をした段階で、Travis CIとGitHubは連携出来ており、buildされテストされるはずなのですが、buildされません。

どうすれば良いでしょうか？

#### 追記

[docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/)
にある内容について追記致します。
To get started with Travis CI using GitHub
のところで、①②③について、
③のところは、the green Activate buttonとは、Sync Accountのボタンのことではないでしょうか？
これを押すと"Syncing form GitHub"となり、なかなかSyncしてくれません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
終わったように見える画面になっても、常にロード中になってしまいます。

お願い致します。

Comment: ビルドされない、というのは、Travis 側でビルドが開始されないということでしょうか。ビルドは開始されるがエラーになる、ということでは無いということですよね。もしそうであれば、Rails 側というよりかは Travis 側でどのような設定を行ったかについて、[edit] して追記をお願いしたいです。具体的には Travis CI のチュートリアル https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/ に書かれているようなことを行っているかどうかが気になっています。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！[docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/)に関して追記致しました！お願い致します！

Comment: 仰る通り、「ビルドは開始されるがエラーになる」ではなく、「ビルドが開始されない」ということです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> これを押すと"Syncing form GitHub"となり、なかなかSyncしてくれません。

これが原因です。

この問題は Travis CI のフォーラムでも話題になっており、私の知る限り未解決のはず……です。

フォーラムの情報をまとめると以下の通りです。

- Travis CI にログアウト＆ログインして解決する場合がある。
- それでも駄目なら Travis CI のサポートに連絡してアカウントの状態を直してもらうことで解決したことがある。

https://travis-ci.community/t/stuck-on-syncing-from-github/2882

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。buildに関して解決致しましたので、報告致します。
アカウントの認証プロセスが途中でした。申し訳ありません。ですが、"We are unable to start your build at this time. You exceeded the number of users allowed for your plan. Please review your plan details and follow the steps to resolution."というメッセージが認証後に出まして、Support Engineerに質問したところ、Free planに加入する手続きが必要とのことでした。Free planに加入すると無事解決致しました。また、"Syncing form GitHub"となったままになる件については解決致しませんでした。これについては今Engineerに質問しております。Travis CIのフォーラムも参考にさせて頂きます。ありがとうございます。
また分かりましたら、報告させて頂きます。
この度はありがとうございます。